# In the Glycolysys Sel'kov model, what are the meaning of "a" and "b" values?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, biology

In the Sel'kov model of glycolysis which I put on next

$u'=-u+av+u^2v\\
v'=b-av-u^2v$

which have a limit cycle and have all sense because it is a glycolytic cycle. What are the biological-medical-physical meaning of the letters $a$ and $b$ in this model?.

I've been reading the original Sel'kov research, and I can figure it that the meaning of $b$ refers to **phosphofructiquinase**, but I've beein reading a lot of biological texts about glycolysis and I can't find the meaning of the $a$.

Since I'm a mathematician, trying to develop this research in biomathematics, but I don't have the slightest idea of what biological meaning does the $a$ have.

Is there anybody who can give a tip or maybe somebody who's in the same research line (biomathematics) who can give me a text or amplify my mind of the biological meaning of $a$.

If somebody needs the original text in order to read it, I'll be glad to share it with all of you.

Thanks.

Comment: I found that $b$ is named phosphofructokinase and $a$ is called hexokinase wich is the activant from all the glycolytic cycle and the  phosphofructokinase is the one who's in charge of the continuation of the cycle.